# getting MAC address of system: eth0 vs PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames

Tags: linux, networking, mac-address

I wrote some C code having a rudimentary software licensing function within, where the executable will only run if the MAC address of the system I whitelisted in my C code.  I only want this to work in linux.

I was accessing `/sys/class/net/eth0/address` which contains something like `a0:b1:c2:d3:e4:f5` all in lower case on one line, making it very easy to get the MAC address.  This works only if you have `eth0` because I hard coded `fopen( "/sys/class/net/eth0/address", "r" );`

The problem I am realizing is the **eth0** part.  With BiosDevName and/or Predictable Network Interface Naming being the default now [in RHEL/CentOS 7] I am seeing something like `eno1` rather than `eth0` as the first network device having a MAC address.  And this can vary greatly from system to system.
So I am dealing with `/sys/class/net/<unknown>/address`.

What is the most portable and reliable, and not to hard, of a way to get the MAC address(es) of a linux system?  Oftentimes the servers I deal with have quad port Intel NIC's, but I really only need the first one.  And my code doesn't care what the network interface names are, I just need to know one or more MAC addresses that are present.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: yeah, I use `popen` in C to parse output of `ifconfig` and wrote a significant chunk of C to do so, since the output of `ifconfig` varies between linux distro's.  Using `/sys/class/net/<unknown>/address` is not readable by anyone other than root which posed a problem.

Comment: You should post that as an answer then to help future people. However, those files can be read by non-root users at least on CentOS 7 and Debian; the permissions are set to 444.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to pull MAC addresses for a system and pair to an interface, we can do this Bash and feed it to the C program. If we look in `/sys/class/net/*/`, we can see that an interface's name is contained in the `uevent` file, while the MAC address is in the `address` file; so, we can combine those two files together per interface. Note: My bash isn't the prettiest, there is probably a better way to do this.

```
[user@headdesk eth0]$ cat /sys/class/net/*/uevent /sys/class/net/*/address | grep -v IFINDEX | column | sed 's/INTERFACE=//'
eth0            fa:16:3e:ac:48:74
lo              00:00:00:00:00:00
```